# GIT Rebasing specific usecase

Tags: git, bitbucket, rebase

I created a Feature branch from a Release branch and rebased the feature branch to a previous commit(git rebase commit_id), did a force push the feature branch to the remote feature and finally raised a PR for feature-release merging.

After PR got merged, I am seeing **remote branch is not implicitly rebased to the previous commit**.

Is this the expected behaviour?

How can my release branch can also to be rebased to the same previous commit.[**Restriction-> I am not allowed to push commits directly to Release branch, I need to do it via a feature branch & PR**]

Comment: When you say _"rebased the feature branch to a previous commit"_, that part needs to specify _how_ you did it. Not because it can't be done... it *can* be done, but it needs... finesse.... and I would like to know _specifically_ how you did it.

Comment: @eftshift0 checked out my feature branch and ran git rebase commit_id

Comment: if you ran a _simple_ rebase, it would **not** work because it would include the commits between the current base and the old commit in the rebase... that's why you end up like that. If you had to do something like `git rebase upstream-branch my-branch --onto old-commit` so that it ddid not include the commits in upstream branch past `the-old-commit`.

Comment: Let me explain a little bit better with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

So... suppose you start with this:

```
* EEE Third commit in main (main)
| * DDD second commit in feature branch (feature)
| * CCC first commit in feature branch
|/
* BBB second commit in main
* AAA first commit in main
```

Suppose you would like to see this:

```
* EEE Third commit in main (main)
* BBB second commit in main
| * DDD' second commit in feature branch (feature)
| * CCC' first commit in feature branch
|/
* AAA first commit in main
```

If you ran: `git checkout feature; git rebase AAA`, what would git do? It would look for the last common ancestor between `AAA` and your branch and apply the commits after it on top of `AAA`... last common ancestor of `AAA` and `feature`? It's `AAA`. Then commits to be applied? `AAA..feature`, which would be `BBB`, `CCC` and `DDD`.... so you are not really getting anything, you end up with the same branch history (if I recall how git behaves in this scenario where you are introducing no changes in history)... or, worst case scenario (if it *does* rewrite history... which I doubt), with this:

```
* EEE Third commit in main (main)
* BBB second commit in main
| * DDD' second commit in feature branch (feature)
| * CCC' first commit in feature branch
| * BBB' second commit in main
|/
* AAA first commit in main
```

Which is even worse because you have unwillingly created a duplicate of `BBB`.

What you need to tell git is to *avoid* introducing `BBB`. You can do it by specifying either `BBB` like this: `git rebase BBB feature --onto AAA` or using the upstream branch like this: `git rebase main feature --onto AAA`.

The way I read that: `git rebase discard-commits-in-the-history-of-this-commit what-to-rebase --onto the-new-base`.